# How to run code editor in android app

Tags: php, android, jquery, android-intent

Hello everyone,
          i am trying to run my code editor into my android app here is my link of  editor [webpage code editor](http://guru99.com/demo-editor-php.html)

i am using the below code for my code editor
[code link](http://jsbin.com/xeqagafa/1/watch?html)

and it works good in my web page but if i put the same code in my android app then its not working. 
you can check the editor in my android app in course testing&Qa> jmeter and lession11 at the last but for check that You need internet connection
my app link :- [android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vector.guru99&hl=en)

if you do not hve android mobile then here is my screenshots after upload above code in my lession 
[screentshot1](http://screencast.com/t/3lEP9YsFR) 
if i press run button then
[after press run button](http://screencast.com/t/orgCqApD)

if i choose chrome
[after choose crome](http://screencast.com/t/HVXOduS25enP)